# Why is it a security concern to modify http.sys registry entries to allow web service to accept a longer query string?

Tags: web-application, http, webserver, iis

I have an Http web service running on IIS. The Http service will be exposed to the public internet, but only authenticated client requests will be processed by the web service. The service allows clients to write complex queries using query parameters like `$filter=foo eq 5 or bar eq "abc"...` to query the backend database.

I want to allow my clients to potentially have query string up to 2 MB depending on their needs. Currently, I can start small at something like 64KB.

Default query string size for IIS is [2KB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-bad-request-response-kerberos#workaround-2-set-maxfieldlength-and-maxrequestbytes-registry-entries), which I increased to 16KB. Increasing it to anything more than that requires changing `http.sys` registry settings: `MaxRequestBytes` `MaxFieldLength`. The [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-bad-request-response-kerberos#workaround-2-set-maxfieldlength-and-maxrequestbytes-registry-entries) on this very clearly states:

> Changing these registry keys should be considered to be extremely dangerous. These keys allow larger HTTP packets to be sent to IIS. This, in turn, may cause Http.sys to use more memory. Therefore, such changes can increase the computer's vulnerability to malicious attacks.

Now I am trying to find guidance on what the best practices are to increase query string size.

(1) I keep reading that there are security "risks", but how can I increase query string size while mitigating these "risks"?

(2) What exactly are all the risks?

(3) I am thinking, maybe I can have my clients provide the query string in the request body. Would that mitigate the "risks"?

Comment: I believe `http.sys` has some formally verified code. Changing those parameters may render the verification results invalid.

Comment: `This, in turn, may cause Http.sys to use more memory`: resource exhaustion attack.

Comment: Why doesn't http.sys/http servers have restrictions on request body to the same degree as query string, if memory usage is a security vulnerability. Is there any way to mitigate resource exhaustion attacks while at the same time increasing these limits.

Comment: There is a [limit](https://windoh.wordpress.com/2014/05/18/upload-large-content-with-http-sys-iis-asp-and-asp-net/). One cannot upload a 1TB file. I'd advise you to redesign and avoid such large query strings. Also, just because a user is authenticated doesn't mean they're trusted. A compromised account will quickly highlight this.

Comment: I don't need 1TB query strings, 2.5MB max. The only option I see is to move it to a POST request body whose limits seem to be at least a bit more larger than 16KB, but what I want to first know is why is this more secure than increasing the query size limits. If they both increase DDOS attacks by the same risk factor, then I rather just change the query string limit then introduce a new endpoint.

Comment: Some intermediary agents (proxy, load balancers, etc.) will apply arbitrary limits (usually around 8k) that would break your web app. In the past several attacks on HTTP servers written in C on url paring had been performed (like integer rotation, buffer stuff, etc.) so all http servers tends to consider that long urls are mostly made by attackers. Use POST queries for robust large data processing.